# Which unique dwellers can be found?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I was wondering, what unique dwellers can be found inside the lunchboxes?

Currently I just got "Three Dog" from Fallout 3 inside my last lunchbox. He has a really high `C` stat (10 including his unique outfit) and comes along with lvl 45.

Which unique dwellers can be found in those lunchboxes?

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of characters from Fallout 3 can be found, more specifically important(ish) characters, such as Amata, Allistair Tenpenny, Butch, etc. 21 total characters can be found, but for some reason, it doesn't seem like characters from any other game in the series (that I noticed) are obtainable. Here's a wiki link for a list of names.

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_characters

Comment: The list is missing a few names (Ivan White I got is one of the missing) in there. There's more than that.